# Let $G$ be finite group and $H<G$. For every proper subgroup $K$, $[G:H]\leq[H:K]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and $H<G$. For every proper subgroup $K$, $[G:H]\leq[H:K]$.

I want to prove $H$ is normal subgroup.

I fixed $K:=g^{-1}Hg$ but this doesn't work. Can somebody advise me?

Comment: $K=G$ is a subgroup and $[G:G]=1$, so the inequality forces $H=G$, which is clearly normal.

Comment: $K\neq G$, since $K$ is a proper subgroup

Comment: Why should someone think on a question whose assumptions are being changed frequently( at least 3 times)??!!

Comment: is this homework or your conjecture?

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang The original post did not have that condition in it, hence my comment and the subsequent edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you try other ways?

Assume to contrary, there exists element $g$ such that $H^g\neq H$. By assumption, we have $[G:H]\leq[H:H^g\cap H]$. Thus we can conclude that $|G|\leq|HH^g|$ and so $G=HH^g$.

It is not hard to see that it is contradiction because there exist elements $h_1,H_2\in H$ such that $g=h_1g^{-1}h_2g$. Hence $g\in H$.

Comment: Why does that imply $g\in H$?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy It implies that $h_1g^{-1}h_2=1\in H$. So we deduce that $g\in H$.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Take $G=A_n$, $n\geq 5$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for any $K$ a subgroup of $G$, we have $|K|\leq |H|$. Then $[G:H]\leq [G:K]$ for any proper subgroup $K$ of $G$. But $H$ is not normal in $G$, since $G$ is a simple group.

Comment: what do you take $H$? how do you check [G:H]\leq [G:K]? By GAP? I don't think that it is easy to see.

Comment: can you tell me why my solution is wrong?

Comment: @Babgen: I could not follow haw $|G| \leq |HH^g|$. I think the mistake is here.

Comment: @Babgen: It could be done via GAP. I think we can make another contradiction as well by considering a group in which $H\neq N_G(H)$.

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang I changed a little in my solution then it is right now

Comment: @Babgen: I still dont follow why $|G| \leq |HH^g|$?

Comment: Ah, yes, and now I see why my argument falls through.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: That is a very good news, that you can correct your own mistake. I just hope that one day you will see what i wrote is correct or wrong.

Comment: @Babgen  Consider the set of all proper subgroups of $G$.  Since $G$ is finite, this set is finite, and in particular the set of orders of proper subgroups of $G$ is finite.  Pick any subgroup corresponding to the maximum such order.  For $A_5$, this order will be 12, and there are 5 subgroups of this order in $A_5$.

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang Oh, yours is definitely correct.  $A_5$ is certainly a counterexample.  As is any other simple group, using the idea in my previous comment.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Now you got it and thank you for the comment